# how to convert pandas dataframe into the following format

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dataframe and want to convert to the following format,
Original:

```
   gender   count  
0  female  10
1  male  20
```

Ideal:

```
female :  10
male :  20
```

Remove the header, and add ":" in between. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you want a string formatted like that? Or do you want a dictionary?

Comment: I would like a dictionary without the bracket and separate into two lines. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

One way by using `iterrows`

```
for _,y in df.iterrows():
    print('{0}:{1}'.format(y['gender'],y['count']))

female:10
male:20
```

I prefer using dict

```
df.set_index('gender').T.to_dict('r')
Out[749]: [{'female': 10, 'male': 20}]
```